# html regex validation limit only one period on decimal input

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I made a HTML input which accepts decimal only.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="price" name="price" placeholder="Price" 
onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'')">
```

This is working. However I need to modify the regex to accept only one period

Correct: 9.999

Wrong: 9.9.99.99

Is there a way? please don't use jquery validate and html type="number" (Users doesn't want the up and down arrow when you set the input to type number) Thanks

Comment: [`\d+(\.\d+)?`](https://regex101.com/r/bM0gC8/1) [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/o092qx6t/)

Answer (score 0):

Sharing this answer to limit one period on decimal input

replace

```
this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'')
```

with

```
this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1')
```